# There is already an object named ""; in the database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using pyspark in databricks to append data to a sql table via ADF pipelines. Code is sown below:

```
log_status_df_all = spark.createDataFrame(log_status_df_all)
log_status_df_all.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode(write_mode).option("url", url).option("dbtable", 'Logs_Collection_Status').option("user", username).option("password", password).save()
log_status_df_all.show()
```

On some days I am get the error message:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named &#39;<table_name>&#39; in the database.`

Upon simply re-running the pipeline the table is updated with no issues; therefore the code is working. How can I prevent this from happening again? Is it an error when multiple pipelines try writing to the same table at the same time?

The rest of the error message is shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last) 
<command-3143827225825384> in <module>

      8 
      9   log_collection_df = spark.createDataFrame(log_collection_df)
---> 10   write_df_sql(log_collection_df, 'Logs_Collection_Status', 'overwrite')
     11 

<command-1421348210166948> in write_df_sql(df, table, write_mode)
     14 
     15 
---> 16   spark_df.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode(write_mode).option("url", url).option("dbtable", table_name).option("user", username).option("password", password).save()
     17 
     18   #backup table

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    735             self.format(format)
    736         if path is None:
--> 737             self._jwrite.save()
    738         else:
    739             self._jwrite.save(path)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)    1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
= get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o661.save. : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'Logs_Collection_Status' in the database.     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:845)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:752)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:680)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.BulkCopyUtils$.executeUpdate(BulkCopyUtils.scala:456)     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.BulkCopyUtils$.mssqlCreateTable(BulkCopyUtils.scala:495)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.SingleInstanceConnector$.createTable(SingleInstanceConnector.scala:33)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.Connector.write(Connector.scala:60)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:51)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:152)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:193)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:189)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:140)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:117)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:115)    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:113)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:243)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:99)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:173)  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:307)   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor841.invoke(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Added snipet above.

Comment: >Is it an error when multiple pipelines try writing to the same table at the same time?

No. Multiple pipelines can write to the same table.  That is fine. It is an error if multiple pipelines are trying to create the table.

Comment: Does the `write.format()` command create the table if it doesn't exist?  Are any other commands deleting that table?  Are you sure it isn't a concurrency issue?

Comment: Yes, `write.format()` always creates a table if it does not exit in the SQL database.  The table definitely exists as other pipelines are writing to it. Does it matter if I am overwriting the table or appending to it? There is no command deleting the table. It could be a concurrency issue, as the issue only happens when pipelines are running or when the same script is running multiple times in parallel. How would I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has now been resolved.

Previous code:

```
if condition1==True: 
     write_mode = 'overwrite' 
elif condition2==True:
      write_mode = 'append'


log_status_df_all = spark.createDataFrame(log_status_df_all)
log_status_df_all.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode(write_mode).option("url", url).option("dbtable", 'Logs_Collection_Status').option("user", username).option("password", password).save()  
log_status_df_all.show()
```

Current code:

```
write_mode = 'append'

log_status_df_all = spark.createDataFrame(log_status_df_all)
log_status_df_all.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode(write_mode).option("url", url).option("dbtable", 'Logs_Collection_Status').option("user", username).option("password", password).save()  
log_status_df_all.show()
```